# Site Broke only in FireFox

Tags: css, wordpress, firefox

a friend of mine have a problem is his website, I already fixed some errors, but nothing seems to work. The website broke only in Firefox and IE. I can´t find the error. Anyone knows a better way to check which error might be the problem?

Link:
http://www.mitografias.com.br/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem may be caused by incorrect markup.

The random image the you have in the header is not formed properly. Since you are not using the HTML5 doctype you need to include the `<img/>` closing tag.

The correct markup needs to have the `/` like this:

```
<img src="random.php" height="200" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Having block elements in an inline element causes firefox trouble. You can learn more about that here https://blog.mozilla.org/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/